# How to verify input in UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have a piece of code:

```
  NSString *favoriteName = nil;
    if (self.favTextField.text != nil) {
        favoriteName = self.favTextField.text;
    } else
    {
        favoriteName = self.defaultName;
    }
```

This is for when I press save name button, and the textfield text is nil it will be the default name. However, when I click on the textfield but don't type anything and save. It will save empty. How can I fix that, I want it will still save the default name if I click on the text field but don't type anything? Please help me out.

Btw: i have try self.favTextField.text isEqualToString:@"" it still does not work.

Comment: Is favoriteName correct when text is in the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try testing for string length.

```
if ([self.favTextField.text length]==0) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *trimmedString = [self.favTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if (trimmedString.length > 0){
    favoriteName = self.favTextField.text;
}
else{
    favoriteName = self.defaultName;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't need to trim some characters